# Lightning Inputfield Conditional Required Field

Tags: lightning, aura, conditional, required-field

I am trying to make one of my input fields conditionally required based on a checkbox value of false.  Is this possible using a standard 'required' attribute in Lightning/Aura?  The below doesn't seem to be working for me using the required attribute.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! rt.Name == 'RT'}">

<lightning:inputField aura:id="Budget__c" fieldName="Budget__c"
 value="{!v.Package.Budget__c}" required ="{!v.Package.Checkbox__c == false}"/> 

</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add required attribute based with `true/false` value.

If your field value is Boolean `v.Package.Checkbox__c` then directly add your values.

**Example:**

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="Budget__c" fieldName="Budget__c"
 value="{!v.Package.Budget__c}" required="{!v.Package.Checkbox__c}"/>
```

Ref : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! rt.Name == 'RT'}">

<lightning:inputField aura:id="Budget__c" fieldName="Budget__c"
 value="{!v.Package.Budget__c}" required ="{!v.Package.Checkbox__c == false}" disabled="false" required = "true"/> 

</aura:if>
```

Comment: Duplicate `required` Attribute is not good